# I would like to echo/access the filter or where clause in my stored procedure in SQL 2005 when called called from Access .adp report

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, stored-procedures

I am calling a report which is linked to a stored procedure from my Access 2010 .adp file

For example:

```
  DoCmd.OpenReport "r_my_report", acPreview, , "xxx=" & Chr(34) & xxx & Chr(34)
```

Is it possible to echo the where clause or the filter parameter and do some logic on it in the stored procedure? Do these parameters come into the stored procedure in a way that you can use them, or does access just feed them directly to the SQL engine behind the scenes? Can I even just echo or log the actual query that is executed?

I am climbing the learning curve on this, so thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Access .adp provides a fairly direct interface to SQL server, the stored procedure you see in the adp is an actual stored procedure in SQL Server database.

You have a report based on a stored procedure with a filter, what is probably happening is the stored procedure is executed with it's parameters, the data set is then passed back to the client where it is then filtered by the client.

If you'd used a view instead of a stored procedure then the query would probably converted and passed to the sql server, the server's optimiser would then have worked out a plan to optimise it's execution including the fields from the where clause.

To find out what is happening on the server use the SQL Server Profiler, this will give you a list of all queries as the run against the server along with some statistics. You may find access is being cleverer than you expect.

Comment: I had understood that the where clause was passed to the server so the server would not return unneeded data to the client?

Comment: One thing that SQL can't do is 'SELECT myfields FROM mystoredprocedure WHERE mycriteria = 1' a stored procedure needs to be executed with it's parameters i.e. 'EXEC mystoredprocedure myparam1, myparam2'. A view is different as you can 'SELECT myfields FROM myview WHERE mycriteria = 1' and it can optimise based on that criteria.

Comment: A paremeterized query on a view accomplishes the same thing along with optimization.

Comment: So how do I get the parameter I want for my view from Access to the stored procedure? How do I echo it -- so I can see what it is? How do I modify it when it arrives?  I still want to do something with the parameter in the stored procedure. My stored procedure is where I would like to put the logic of my program.  So far the only thing I have had any luck with is using a separate table with my parameter in it, and retrieving that at the start of my stored procedure, but that seems kinda clumsy and its not multi-user friendly. Thanks for your help so far!